# how to setup CVS pserver in linux

Tags: cvs

I am new to CVS. I recently installed CVS repository. I have imported my project into CVS. Now I need to access my CVS repositroy locally but I am not able to access getting below error

on remote m/c 
export CVSROOT=:pserver:cvs@:/etc/cvs/source

cvs login
Logging in to :pserver:cvs:2401/etc/cvs/source
CVS password: 
cvs [login aborted]: connect to [Host_name]:2401 failed: Connection refused

Checked on CVS server that port 2401 is not running. Any pointer how to start/open port 2401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some instructions for adding a pserver:
http://comsci.liu.edu/~murali/cvs/pserver.htm

Comment: You probably don't have write permission to your repository directory. BTW, it's not a great practice to have your repository in /etc I think.

Comment: Thanks for details. I have moved repository to other mount with enough space.

Comment: The link is broken. Maybe more info from the link will help to make this answer more readable.

Answer (score 1):

update the file /etc/xinetd.conf

```
service cvspserver
{
port = 2401
socket_type = stream
protocol = tcp
wait = no
user = test 
server = /usr/bin/cvs
server_args = -f --allow-root=/test --allow-root=/test2 pserver 
}
```

service xinetd restart

This creates two repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I created file as root /etc/xinetd.d/cvspserver with below contents

```
service cvspserve
{
disable = no
socket_type = stream
protocol = tcp
user = root
wait = no
server = /usr/bin/cvs
server_args = -f --allow-root=/etc/cvs/source pserver
log_on_success +=USERID
log_on_failure += USERID
```

}

and restarted xinetd as below as root service xinetd restart. It worked and I could login but while checking out getting this error

cvs checkout: failed to create lock directory for

Comment: have you managed to solve this? I am also getting the same error. This is for new cvs installation